# How to change keyboard backlight timeout setting in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, hp-pavilion, backlight

I have a HP Pavilion 15-bc513TX 2019 laptop. The keyboard backlight goes out after a few minutes in the dark.

How can I change the keyboard backlight settings for my computer running Windows?

Comment: Your support page, bookmark it for later reference....https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-bc500-laptop/26122243/model/29678373/manuals

Comment: Yes the manual says it turns off after 30 seconds, how annoying, I haven't found a way to disable this feature yet. I am sure they have done this so they can publish longer battery run time.

Comment: Yeah its really annoying.Please tell me when you find a way. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You might ask on this forum.....https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/bd-p/Hardware